# How to Convert Currency Formatted Text to Double Value or NSNumber Value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to convert currency to double value

In My app I have a textField which displays Currency Like

$1,234,567.00

I can Easily remove the $ sign by substrings

But Is there any Formatter style that can make it to the Double?
Actually when I am doing

vardouble=[txtfield.text doublevalue];

because of comma it shows 1.00(above value).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
double d = [[nf numberFromString:@"$1,234,567.00"] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

1) First remove commas using `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement;`

2) then Call `[yourString doubleValue]`

Comment: @Arpit Parekh, You should consider using `NSNumberFormatter`

Comment: @Arpit -  please use solution given by EmptyStack .