# Converting currency text values (like $1234.56) to float

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an UITextField where the user enters currency value like $1,234.56. In an iPhone app, how can I convert that value to float?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-Apply currency formatting to a UITextField on a change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388448/re-apply-currency-formatting-to-a-uitextfield-on-a-change-event)

Comment: Do not use a float for money.  Either use NSDecimal or an integer multiplied (scaled) by 100.  Eventually there will be an arithmetic operation on the value that will cause rounding errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to float in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831188/string-to-float-in-objective-c) or [Convert currency formatted text to double value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343785/how-to-convert-currency-formatted-text-to-double-value-or-nsnumber-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an `NSNumberFormatter` to go back and forth between a value `1234.56` and a string `@"$1,234.56"`.

Apple has a very good [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html) to walk you through setting up and using a currency formatter.

In order to integrate this with a UITextField, you will want to use the delegate method

– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

This allows you to validate and update characters as the user types them in. For an example of how to implement this, look at this post: [Re-Apply currency formatting to a UITextField on a change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388448/re-apply-currency-formatting-to-a-uitextfield-on-a-change-event)